# With django templates, how to remove the last item newline in a loop

Tags: python, django, templates

I would like to use the Django template engine to build some text files :

I wrote this script :

```
from django.template import Template, Context
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()
with open('etchosts') as fh:
    t = Template(fh.read().strip())
    c = Context({'hosts': ['host A','host B', 'host C']})
    print t.render(c)
```

And the template file "etchosts" :

```
=================================
{% for h in hosts %} - {{ h }}
{% endfor %}
=================================
```

If I run the script I got :

```
=================================
 - host A
 - host B
 - host C
                <----- unwanted newline
=================================
```

As you see, there is an unwanted newline at the end of the loop

How can I change my template to have :

```
=================================
 - host A
 - host B
 - host C
=================================
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in a for loop, an extra object named `forloop` is present. This contains some information about the loop. See [this documentation page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for).

In your case, the code would be something like this:

```
=================================
{% for h in hosts %} - {{ h }}{% if not forloop.last %}
{% endif %}{%endfor %}
=================================
```

Question is, is the above cleaner then your current solution? Personally I think the extra code in the solution above messes things up, but that is just a personal preference. However, it is a valid alternative (and as a bonus, now you know about the forloop object).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `{% if forloop.last %}` to check if you're in the last iteration. See [the docs for `for`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#for).

Answer (score 0):

```
=================================
{% for h in hosts %} - {{ h }}
{% endfor %}=================================
```

Is the answer, but is there something nicer ?